# Is it possible to check and or change the value of a bound variable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Currently**

1. I have a parent component in react passing a function to a child component
2. The child component adds a variable to the function
3. The function has an optional callback, and when provided the function runs logging 2 console messages (as expected):

> hello world!
>
> hello mars!

**React script:**

```js
    class App extends Component {
    
        parentFunction = (optional_callback, variable_defined_in_child) => {
            console.log("hello " + variable_defined_in_child);
            if (optional_callback) {optional_callback()};
        }
    
        myCallback = () => {
            console.log("hello mars!");
        }
        
        render () {
            <ChildComponent
                myFunction = {this.parentFunction.bind(this, myCallback)}
            />
        }
    }
    
    const ChildComponent = props => {
        const newVariable = "world!";
        props.myFunction(newVariable);
    }
```

**Problem**

If the callback is not provided, the expectation is to receive console message:

> hello world!

But instead the `variable_defined_in_child` is positioned in place of `optional_callback` and the function fails.

**Question**

Is it possible to access the bound variables of `props.myFunction` from the child component, check if it has a callback, and if not, provide as `null`?

- Note: I am relatively new to react, so do let me know if I am coding with an anti-pattern, but if not, I would like to understand if my request is possible rather than refactoring the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `parentFunction` to be a function that returns another function. (It may look complicated if you're new to the concept but don't worry.)

Imagine `parentFunction` to be:

```
parentFunction = optional_callback => variable_defined_in_child => {
    console.log("hello " + variable_defined_in_child);
    if (optional_callback) {
        optional_callback();
    }
};
```

And then you pass it to `ChildComponent` this way:

```
<ChildComponent
    myFunction={this.parentFunction.bind(this, this.myCallback)()}
/>
```

**So what is going on here?**

You are binding `parentFunction` with `this` and passing `this.myCallback` as an argument to it and THEN **invoking** it.

This returns a function which accepts a single argument `variable_defined_in_child` that does exactly what you want: `console.log` and so... while having access to `this.myCallback` without passing it as an argument.

If you don't pass `this.myCallback` to `parentFunction`, everything still works fine.

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1oo4k4xmlq)

Your code will be:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  parentFunction = optional_callback => variable_defined_in_child => {
    console.log("hello " + variable_defined_in_child);
    if (optional_callback) {
      optional_callback();
    }
  };

  myCallback = () => {
    console.log("hello mars!");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent
        myFunction={this.parentFunction.bind(this, this.myCallback)()}
      />
    );
  }
}

const ChildComponent = props => {
  const newVariable = "world!";
  props.myFunction(newVariable);
  return <div />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The problem remains if the positioning of the required argument and the optional callback are switched. The required argument is defined in the child component, and not the parent. I could put a dummy value for the required argument, but i’d still need to access and change it in the child.

Comment: @Wronski You're right, I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: That's a really interesting solution. I am trying to get the no callback version of your code working. Here is the script https://codesandbox.io/s/n7w5yqy90j where all I did was remove "this.myCallback()". It doesn't generate a console log. My assumption would be that the console would log "hello world!".

Comment: You forgot to invoke `this.parentFunction.bind(this)` function with `()`. The correct form of not sending `this.myCallback()` would be `this.parentFunction.bind(this)()`. Note the `()` at the end of it. It's a function that returns another function so you should invoke it to return the one that has `console.log()` and so... Here is the 
script https://codesandbox.io/s/13vomjxroq

Comment: @Wronski If you find it useful, please mark it as answer to help future visitors.

Comment: I did find it useful, but ultimately it implies the actual answer to my question which is that you cannot access the bound variables in intermediary components i.e. change arguments bound to a function.

I ended up reworking my code to go with your first suggestion which was to put callback in last position. Thank you for all your help.